# PDF special char in TJ operator, base 14 fonts

Tags: pdfbox

Is there any way to use special characters like 'rcaron'(U+0159, ř) in TJ operator in base14 fonts (Helvetica)?

Something like [(\rcaron)] TJ ?

Is it present in the font?

I went through Helvetica.afm and it seems that this character is present in the font. Also when I use this character in an interactive textfield in PDF it seems to be present.

I tried pdfbox to generate a sample file, but it fails - it uses  TJ and the character is not correct.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which encoding have you selected for Helvetica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concerning the character set PDF viewers must support for un-embedded base14 fonts, the PDF specification ISO 32000-1 states in section 9.6.2.2:

> The character sets and encodings for these fonts are listed in Annex D.

and  in annex D.1:

> D.2, "Latin Character Set and Encodings", describes the entire character set for the Adobe standard Latin-text fonts. This character set shall be supported by the Times, Helvetica, and Courier font families, which are among the standard 14 predefined fonts; see 9.6.2.2, "Standard Type 1 Fonts (Standard 14 Fonts)".

If you inspect the tables in D.2, you'll see that rcaron is not explicitly supported, only scaron, zcaron, and a naked caron. The latter indicates that you can construct a rcaron. Unfortunately, though, the table states that the naked caron is not available in **WinAnsiEncoding** which is the standard encoding assumed in PDFBox.

Thus, to draw the unembedded base14 Helvetica rcaron you essentially will have to use a Helvetica font object with a non-**WinAnsiEncoding** encoding, e.g. **MacRomanEncoding**.

Furthermore you have to adapt the encoding of the strings added to your content streams. If you e.g. used to use `PDPageContentStream.drawString(String)`, you'll have to change that because that method uses the `COSString(String)` constructor which implicitly assumes other encodings ("ISO-8859-1" or "UTF-16BE") not appropriate for the task at hand.

Comment: Yes, that's probably the answer I needed. Thank you :)